# Random 500 server error with Puma after update to Rails 6, and no log or feedback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I cannot solve an issue.

```
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 48063], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE UserProfile Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "user_profiles".* FROM "user_profiles" WHERE "user_profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 48063], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered collection of contents/_author.html.haml [1 times] (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 295)
  Rendered commentables/_comments_count.html.haml (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 124)
  Section Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections" INNER JOIN "sectionable_sections" ON "sections"."id" = "sectionable_sections"."section_id" WHERE "sectionable_sections"."sectionable_id" = $1 AND "sectionable_sections"."sectionable_type" = $2 ORDER BY "sections"."position" ASC  [["sectionable_id", 35008], ["sectionable_type", "Content"]]
  Rendered contents/_article_teaser.html.haml (Duration: 4.4ms | Allocations: 2781)
  Rendering app/cells/products/index.html.haml
   (0.2ms)  SELECT MAX("products"."updated_at") FROM "products" WHERE "products"."state" = $1 AND "products"."published_at" <= '2020-04-24 10:10:03.771036'  [["state", "active"]]
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."state" = $1 AND "products"."published_at" <= '2020-04-24 10:10:03.771036'  [["state", "active"]]
  Product Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."state" = $1 AND "products"."published_at" <= '2020-04-24 10:10:03.771036' ORDER BY "products"."published_at" DESC LIMIT $2  [["state", "active"], ["LIMIT", 10]]
  Rendered app/cells/products/_product_widget.html.haml (Duration: 1638.9ms | Allocations: 975442)
  Rendered app/cells/products/index.html.haml (Duration: 1643.5ms | Allocations: 976263)
  Rendered home/_aside_4.html.haml (Duration: 1644.2ms | Allocations: 976734)
  Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (Duration: 1941.8ms | Allocations: 1085299)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1979ms (ActiveRecord: 155.0ms | Allocations: 1103473)
```

Sometimes I have during development this Puma server errors. I've not deployed the code on my staging server, but I'm worried about these errors.

No log, nothing. If I exit and I restart the server everything is ok, so is not a code issue.
Any idea?

Comment: Possibly memory issue. Does the puma process get enough memory?

Comment: It’s a MacBook 16 with two puma process

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in `config/environments/development.rb` and use:

```
##config/environments/development.rb
config.log_level = :debug ## add this line
```

This should at least get you some sort of backtrace so you can start to find the problem.

Comment: I create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/robypez/b955c40657c0779e1cdf079677107eef)

Comment: Check this hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879629/logs-both-development-and-product-and-server-output-not-working-rails-3